# R `randomForest` - number of terminal nodes in trained forest (maxnodes not nodesize)

Tags: r, random-forest

How to compute `maxnodes` for forest for which `maxnodes` parameter have not been defined ?

`maxnodes: Maximum number of terminal nodes trees in the forest can
          have.  If not given, trees are grown to the maximum possible
          (subject to limits by ‘nodesize’).  If set larger than
          maximum possible, a warning is issued.`

**maxnodes is not nodesize**

Comment: By default, trees are fully grown. This means 1 observation in every node for regression and 5 for classification.

Comment: Just look at the definition of `nodesize` in the documentation: Minimum size of terminal nodes. Setting this number larger causes smaller trees to be grown (and thus take less time). Note that the default values are different for classification (1) and regression (5).

Comment: @Zelazny 7  - `Maximum number of terminal nodes` not the numer of obs in terminal nodes

Answer (score 2):

The number of terminal nodes in each tree of the forest can be found using the "getTree" function. Terminal nodes are indicated by a -1 in the "status" column.

To find the maximum, you would have to find the maximum number of terminal nodes across all trees.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model object loaded into your R workspace named `model`, you can get the maximum number of nodes either interactively or programmatically.

Below is a screenshot of the `View()` command issued on a model trained on the iris dataset with 10 trees. The maximum number of nodes is shown in the dimension for several of those variables: `nodestatus`, `bestvar`, `treemap`, `nodepred`, and `xbestsplit`. In this case it is 9 (the first number in the reported dimension, i.e. 9 x 10).

[image]

The number of nodes for each tree is stored in `ndbigtree`. While it looks like each tree has 9 nodes, one of the later trees actually has only 7 nodes inside it.

Programmatically, you can use this information to get the maximum tree size in several ways.

Maximum number of nodes (terminal or otherwise):

```
dim(model$forest$nodestatus)[1]
```

Maximum number of nodes (terminal):

```
terminalInEachTree = apply(model$forest$nodestatus, 2, function(x) { length(which( x == -1)) } ) # get the number of terminal nodes in each tree
maxOverall = max(terminalInEachTree)
```